# IF=0, COUNTIFS, #NAME? error

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I have a `COUNTIFS` function that is working perfectly, but if I add a `IF=0` to the beginning of the function I get a `#NAME?` error.  I have that technique working in other cells of the Excel file; I have verified spelling and case-sensitive text.  In fact, the cell right next to the `#NAME?` error shows a correct count of `4`.  Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

This works:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Full Database'!B:B,C10,'Full Database'!I:I,">01/01/2018",'Full Database'!I:I,"<01/15/2018",'Full Database'!M:M,"Incorporated in Production")=0,””,COUNTIFS('Full Database'!B:B,C10,'Full Database'!I:I,">01/01/2018",'Full Database'!I:I,"<01/15/2018",'Full Database'!M:M,"Incorporated in Production"))
```

This does not:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Full Database'!B:B,C10,'Full Database'!I:I,">01/16/2018",'Full Database'!I:I,"<01/29/2018",'Full Database'!M:M,"Incorporated in Production")=0,””,COUNTIFS('Full Database'!B:B,C10,'Full Database'!I:I,">01/16/2018",'Full Database'!I:I,"<01/29/2018",'Full Database'!M:M,"Incorporated in Production"))
```

(Yes, the dates are supposed to be different)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're suffering from magic / curly quotes. This is a habit of Microsoft Office that can be incredibly annoying if you're working with any machine-interpreted text. Be careful copy/pasting quotes, dashes, etc... - especially in Word.

Both of your lines make use of curly quotes for the "*value if true*" section of the `IF()`... so I'm surprised that either work for you - unless you copied your question via Word, or it takes the "*value if false*" route.

It's a matter of `"` vs `”` - the first being "*straight*" (ASCII), and the second being "*curly*" (Unicode).

If you replace these with straight quotes, then the evaluation succeeds.

Try using the "*Show Calculation Steps...*" helper, it can be quite useful.

[image: Show Calculation Steps...]

Comment: I didn't even think of the difference between "straight" and "smart" quotes.  That was it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer so that this question is no longer listed as "_unanswered_".